# Is it safe to call dlclose after dlsym

Tags: c++, c, linux, macos

Coming from Windows I'm used to closing the handle to a DLL after getting a pointer to a symbol. Is this the same when using the dl functions? In the example below, will I still be able to use myFunction after dlclose is called? If not, does calling dlclose even matter?

```
void* handle = dlopen ("someLibrary", 0);
if (handle)
{
    myFunction = dlsym (handle, "MyFunction");
    dlclose (handle);
}
```

Comment: Sure, as long as you don't intend to call `myFunction`...

Comment: *Is this the same when using the dl functions?* Yes, LoadLibrary()/FreeLibrary() has same semantics and you were just lucky enough to not experience unmapped library consequences.

Comment: You make a good point, I think the only reason I was unaffected was because the libraries I use are common ones (i.e. kernel32, etc).

Comment: Yes, of course, if the application is already using the shared library/DLL, it will still remain open - there is after all only one actual copy of a shared library within each process [at least without quite a bit of work to make the OS load it more than once]

Comment: Yeah using dispatch_once in an osx library makes dlclose impossible. But I'm sure no one would care since it's ApplicationServices.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`dlclose` closes the shared library (assuming it is the only reference to it), which means that the OS will unmap the shared library, and `MyFunction` is most likely no longer in memory.

Of course, if you do `handle = dlopen("someLibrary", 0); handle2 = dlopen("someLibrary", 0);`, then you can `dlclose(handle);` and the library is still "alive" because there is another reference (`handle2`) to it that is still alive.

It is of course not guaranteed that the OS unmaps it IMMEDIATELY, it may do that as a background process, so it MAY work to call it immediately after close, but not in 0.5 seconds time, or some such. There is no specification saying it must do one or the other, just that it is no longer valid to use

If you only ever open one library, use it throughout your program, then calling `dlclose` just before you exit is probably not essential, but if you open a lot of libraries (e.g. using some sort of plugin in a long-running program that can/will use many different plugins, the program may run out of virtual address space if you don't call `dlclose`.

(All shared libraries are closed on exit anyway, so leaving it open at exit should not be an issue)